# Select lines with repetition using standard command-line tools

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

Given a text file with strings, I would like to draw at random lines with replacement (with repetition).

I know that one can efficiently shuffle the lines with the "shuf" command. What would be the standard linux command-line tools to draw the lines *with* repetition?

My current approach is a Python script that basically generates random numbers in a range [1,N], where N is the number of lines. The generated random number (integers) are used to index the list of strings and then print.

Here is my Python script:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 
  3 from random import random
  4 import sys
  5 
  6 fname = sys.argv[1]
  7 
  8 with open( fname, 'r' ) as f:
  9         lines = f.readlines()
 10 lines = [ s.strip("\n") for s in lines ]
 11 
 12 nlines = len( lines )
 13 
 14 for i in range( nlines ):
 15         idx = round(random()*nlines)
 16         idx = int( idx )
 17         print lines[ idx ]
```

The sample file is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

And the result of running the script on the sample is:

```
c
b
f
b
c
c
b
d
```

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: @AvinashRaj https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm

Comment: @xeon Please specify your examples, code samples in the question.

Comment: some of your code samples please and ppl can help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern versions of `shuf` offer a `-r` option for repeat.  For example:

```
$ cat input
1
2
3
4
5
$ shuf -n 5 -r input
3
2
5
3
3
$ shuf --version
shuf (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Earlier versions of `shuf` may lack `-r`.

#### Alternative: use `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{srand();for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[int(1+NR*rand())]}' input
4
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Excatly what I was looking for! Indeed, on my Ubuntu 14.10 this command has the switch. On the server, which I don't control, there is no such option.

Comment: @xeon For older machines, I add an alternative that use `awk` to generate random lines with repetition.